# Can't connect cardano-wallet with the node on testnet: blockedIndefinitelyException = thread blocked indefinitely in an STM transaction

Tags: wallet, cardano-node, testnet

I'm following this guide https://developers.cardano.org/docs/integrate-cardano/creating-wallet-faucet#creating-a-wallet-with-cardano-wallet
to learn about Cardano infra.

I have cardano-node running on port `3001` using this command

```
    ./cardano-node run \
   --topology ./configuration/cardano/testnet-topology.json \
   --database-path ./configuration/db \
   --socket-path ./configuration/db/node.socket \
   --host-addr 127.0.0.1 \
   --port 3001 \
   --config ./configuration/cardano/testnet-config.json
```

I used the configs that are suggested in the guide. Testnet magic is `1097911063`.

I was able to succesfully generate wallets with `cardano-cli` and create/sign/submit transactions. Now I'm trying to make `cardano-wallet` work but I can't connect to the node. Here is my command:

```
    cardano-wallet serve \
    --port 1337 \
    --testnet configuration/cardano/testnet-byron-genesis.json \
    --database wallets/db \
    --node-socket $CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH
```

This is what I see in the wallet logs before it shots down:

```
[cardano-wallet.main:Info:4] [2021-08-20 06:07:38.48 UTC] Running as v2021-08-11 (git revision: e870e5f05e05e22e4de01672b0e7243b2f907153) on x86_64-darwin
[cardano-wallet.main:Info:4] [2021-08-20 06:07:38.48 UTC] Command line: /usr/local/bin/cardano-wallet serve --port 1337 --testnet configuration/cardano/testnet-byron-genesis.json --database wallets/db --node-socket /Users/[hidden]/[hidden]/cardano-node/configuration/db/node.socket
[cardano-wallet.main:Debug:4] [2021-08-20 06:07:38.48 UTC] ServeArgs {_hostPreference = Host "127.0.0.1", _listen = ListenOnPort 1337, _tlsConfig = Nothing, _nodeSocket = CardanoNodeConn "/Users/[hidden]/cardano-node/configuration/db/node.socket", _networkConfiguration = TestnetConfig "configuration/cardano/testnet-byron-genesis.json", _database = Just "wallets/db", _syncTolerance = SyncTolerance 300s, _enableShutdownHandler = False, _poolMetadataSourceOpt = Nothing, _tokenMetadataSourceOpt = Nothing, _logging = LoggingOptions {loggingMinSeverity = Debug, loggingTracers = Tracers {applicationTracer = Const (Just Info), apiServerTracer = Const (Just Info), tokenMetadataTracer = Const (Just Info), walletEngineTracer = Const (Just Info), walletDbTracer = Const (Just Info), poolsEngineTracer = Const (Just Info), poolsDbTracer = Const (Just Info), ntpClientTracer = Const (Just Info), networkTracer = Const (Just Info)}, loggingTracersDoc = Nothing}}
[cardano-wallet.main:Info:4] [2021-08-20 06:07:38.50 UTC] Wallet databases: Using directory: wallets/db
[cardano-wallet.application:Info:4] [2021-08-20 06:07:38.50 UTC] Wallet backend server starting. Using /Users/[hidden]/Dev/cardano-node/configuration/db/node.socket.
[cardano-wallet.application:Info:4] [2021-08-20 06:07:38.50 UTC] Node is Haskell Node on testnet (1097911063).
[cardano-wallet.token-metadata:Notice:4] [2021-08-20 06:07:38.51 UTC] No token metadata server is configured.
[cardano-wallet.token-metadata:Notice:4] [2021-08-20 06:07:38.51 UTC] No token metadata server is configured.
[cardano-wallet.token-metadata:Notice:4] [2021-08-20 06:07:38.51 UTC] No token metadata server is configured.
[cardano-wallet.token-metadata:Notice:4] [2021-08-20 06:07:38.51 UTC] No token metadata server is configured.
[cardano-wallet.pools-db:Info:4] [2021-08-20 06:07:38.51 UTC] Starting connection pool for wallets/db/stake-pools.sqlite
[cardano-wallet.main:Info:4] [2021-08-20 06:07:38.51 UTC] Wallet backend server listening on http://127.0.0.1:1337/
[cardano-wallet.pools-engine:Info:36] [2021-08-20 06:07:38.53 UTC] Chain following starting. Requesting intersection using 221 checkpoints, the latest being 0ac9b1b6<-[107538a4-213041#211999]
[cardano-wallet.network:Warning:14] [2021-08-20 06:07:38.57 UTC] Connection lost with the node. writev: resource vanished (Broken pipe)
[cardano-wallet.pools-db:Info:4] [2021-08-20 06:07:38.60 UTC] Stopping database connection pool wallets/db/stake-pools.sqlite
[cardano-wallet.pools-db:Info:4] [2021-08-20 06:07:38.60 UTC] Closing single database connection (wallets/db/stake-pools.sqlite)
[cardano-wallet.pools-db:Info:4] [2021-08-20 06:07:38.60 UTC] Closing single database connection (wallets/db/stake-pools.sqlite)
[cardano-wallet.main:Debug:4] [2021-08-20 06:07:38.62 UTC] Logging shutdown.
cardano-wallet: ExceptionInLinkedThread (ThreadId 12) (BlockedIndefinitely {blockedIndefinitelyCallStack = [("wrapBlockedIndefinitely",SrcLoc {srcLocPackage = "io-classes-0.2.0.0-8vqCa9RxYeSIAHkGOEppTU", srcLocModule = "Control.Monad.Class.MonadSTM", srcLocFile = "src/Control/Monad/Class/MonadSTM.hs", srcLocStartLine = 296, srcLocStartCol = 16, srcLocEndLine = 296, srcLocEndCol = 39}),("atomically",SrcLoc {srcLocPackage = "cardano-wallet-core-2021.8.11-9CfWGxilOndlEXObu7PRN", srcLocModule = "Ouroboros.Network.Client.Wallet", srcLocFile = "src/Ouroboros/Network/Client/Wallet.hs", srcLocStartLine = 628, srcLocStartCol = 5, srcLocEndLine = 628, srcLocEndCol = 32})], blockedIndefinitelyException = thread blocked indefinitely in an STM transaction})
```

And this is `cardano-node` logs

```
[MacBook-:cardano.node.LocalErrorPolicy:Error:63] [2021-08-20 06:35:34.08 UTC] IP LocalAddress "" ErrorPolicyUnhandledApplicationException DecoderFailure (LocalStateQuery HardForkBlock (': * ByronBlock (': * (ShelleyBlock (ShelleyEra StandardCrypto)) (': * (ShelleyBlock (ShelleyMAEra 'Allegra StandardCrypto)) (': * (ShelleyBlock (ShelleyMAEra 'Mary StandardCrypto)) ('[] *))))) Query (HardForkBlock (': * ByronBlock (': * (ShelleyBlock (ShelleyEra StandardCrypto)) (': * (ShelleyBlock (ShelleyMAEra 'Allegra StandardCrypto)) (': * (ShelleyBlock (ShelleyMAEra 'Mary StandardCrypto)) ('[] *))))))) ClientAgency TokAcquired) (DeserialiseFailure 7 "EraIndex: invalid index 4")
[MacBook-:cardano.node.LocalErrorPolicy:Error:63] [2021-08-20 06:35:35.15 UTC] IP LocalAddress "" ErrorPolicyUnhandledApplicationException (MuxError (MuxIOException writev: resource vanished (Broken pipe)) "(sendAll errored)")
[MacBook-:cardano.node.LocalErrorPolicy:Error:63] [2021-08-20 06:35:36.15 UTC] IP LocalAddress "" ErrorPolicyUnhandledApplicationException (MuxError MuxBearerClosed "<socket: 34> closed when reading data, waiting on next header True")
[MacBook-:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:33] [2021-08-20 06:37:24.22 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: 8900454c4bb70632d558d70421c2c25e12cc0b448ace065f61f14df882f048f4 at slot 35072228
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing a similar error.

Comment: Could you try running the wallet with the testnet-alonzo genesis file?

Comment: I have a similar problem but on the main net. https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/11164/unable-to-connect-wallet-to-node-on-mainnet

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this will fix your issue, but try running the wallet with the **Alonzo** genesis file instead of Byron?