# Unable to connect wallet to node on mainnet

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, cardano-node

I have been following the instructions here:

https://developers.cardano.org/docs/integrate-cardano/creating-wallet-faucet

I have the node up and running and get the following output from cardano-cli query tip --mainnet:

```
{
    "block": 8929511,
    "epoch": 419,
    "era": "Babbage",
    "hash": "57ed1fb41f5bf65b1f2641e098cb540d9c8480988fcf3109de5c0e35564169a4",
    "slot": 95722889,
    "slotInEpoch": 78089,
    "slotsToEpochEnd": 353911,
    "syncProgress": "100.00"
}
```

When I enter:

```
cardano-wallet serve \
--port 1337 \
--mainnet \
--database $HOME/cardano/wallets/db \
--node-socket $CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH
```

I get the following error:

```
[cardano-wallet.main:Info:4] [2023-06-20 19:24:45.59 UTC] Running as v2023-04-14 (git revision: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000) on x86_64-darwin
[cardano-wallet.main:Info:4] [2023-06-20 19:24:45.59 UTC] Command line: /Users/X/.cabal/store/ghc-9.2.7/crdn-wllt-2023.4.14-878a4af6/bin/cardano-wallet serve --port 1337 --mainnet --database /Users/liam_dolittle/cardano/mainnet/db/ --node-socket /Users/X/cardano/mainnet/db/node.socket --token-metadata-server https://tokens.cardano.org
[cardano-wallet.main:Debug:4] [2023-06-20 19:24:45.59 UTC] ServeArgs {_hostPreference = Host "127.0.0.1", _mode = Normal (CardanoNodeConn "/Users/liam_dolittle/cardano/mainnet/db/node.socket") (SyncTolerance 300s), _listen = ListenOnPort 1337, _tlsConfig = Nothing, _networkConfiguration = MainnetConfig, _database = Just "/Users/X/cardano/mainnet/db/", _enableShutdownHandler = False, _poolMetadataSourceOpt = Nothing, _tokenMetadataSourceOpt = Just (TokenMetadataServer {unTokenMetadataServer = https://tokens.cardano.org}), _logging = LoggingOptions {loggingMinSeverity = Debug, loggingTracers = Tracers {applicationTracer = Const (Just Info), apiServerTracer = Const (Just Info), tokenMetadataTracer = Const (Just Info), walletEngineTracer = Const (Just Info), walletDbTracer = Const (Just Info), poolsEngineTracer = Const (Just Info), poolsDbTracer = Const (Just Info), ntpClientTracer = Const (Just Info), networkTracer = Const (Just Info)}, loggingTracersDoc = Nothing}}
[cardano-wallet.main:Info:4] [2023-06-20 19:24:45.59 UTC] Wallet databases: Using directory: /Users/X/cardano/mainnet/db/
[cardano-wallet.application:Info:4] [2023-06-20 19:24:45.59 UTC] Wallet backend server starting. Using /Users/X/cardano/mainnet/db/node.socket.
[cardano-wallet.application:Info:4] [2023-06-20 19:24:45.59 UTC] Node is Haskell Node on mainnet.
[cardano-wallet.pools-db:Info:4] [2023-06-20 19:24:45.60 UTC] Starting connection pool for /Users/X/cardano/mainnet/db/stake-pools.sqlite
[cardano-wallet.pools-engine:Info:37] [2023-06-20 19:24:45.63 UTC] Chain following starting.
[cardano-wallet.main:Info:4] [2023-06-20 19:24:45.63 UTC] Wallet backend server listening on http://127.0.0.1:1337/
[cardano-wallet.pools-db:Info:4] [2023-06-20 19:24:45.67 UTC] Stopping database connection pool /Users/X/cardano/mainnet/db/stake-pools.sqlite
[cardano-wallet.pools-db:Info:4] [2023-06-20 19:24:45.67 UTC] Closing single database connection (/Users/X/cardano/mainnet/db/stake-pools.sqlite)
[cardano-wallet.main:Debug:4] [2023-06-20 19:24:45.67 UTC] Logging shutdown.
cardano-wallet: ExceptionInLinkedThread (ThreadId 13) DecoderFailure (LocalStateQuery HardForkBlock (': * ByronBlock (': * (ShelleyBlock (TPraos StandardCrypto) (ShelleyEra StandardCrypto)) (': * (ShelleyBlock (TPraos StandardCrypto) (ShelleyMAEra 'Allegra StandardCrypto)) (': * (ShelleyBlock (TPraos StandardCrypto) (ShelleyMAEra 'Mary StandardCrypto)) (': * (ShelleyBlock (TPraos StandardCrypto) (AlonzoEra StandardCrypto)) (': * (ShelleyBlock (Praos StandardCrypto) (BabbageEra StandardCrypto)) (': * (ShelleyBlock (Praos StandardCrypto) (ConwayEra StandardCrypto)) ('[] *)))))))) Query (BlockQuery (HardForkBlock (': * ByronBlock (': * (ShelleyBlock (TPraos StandardCrypto) (ShelleyEra StandardCrypto)) (': * (ShelleyBlock (TPraos StandardCrypto) (ShelleyMAEra 'Allegra StandardCrypto)) (': * (ShelleyBlock (TPraos StandardCrypto) (ShelleyMAEra 'Mary StandardCrypto)) (': * (ShelleyBlock (TPraos StandardCrypto) (AlonzoEra StandardCrypto)) (': * (ShelleyBlock (Praos StandardCrypto) (BabbageEra StandardCrypto)) (': * (ShelleyBlock (Praos StandardCrypto) (ConwayEra StandardCrypto)) ('[] *))))))))))) ServerAgency TokQuerying BlockQuery (QueryIfCurrent (QS (QS (QS (QS (QS (QZ GetCurrentPParams)))))))) (DeserialiseFailure 53 "expected integer")
```

and the following on the node output:

```
[x:cardano.node.LocalErrorPolicy:Error:67] [2023-06-20 19:24:46.65 UTC] IP LocalAddress "/Users/x/cardano/mainnet/db/node.socket@4" ErrorPolicyUnhandledApplicationException (MuxError MuxBearerClosed "<socket: 30> closed when reading data, waiting on next header True")
[x:cardano.node.LocalErrorPolicy:Error:67] [2023-06-20 19:24:46.69 UTC] IP LocalAddress "/Users/x/cardano/mainnet/db/node.socket@5" ErrorPolicyUnhandledApplicationException (MuxError MuxBearerClosed "<socket: 32> closed when reading data, waiting on next header True")
[x:cardano.node.LocalErrorPolicy:Error:67] [2023-06-20 19:24:46.69 UTC] IP LocalAddress "/Users/x/cardano/mainnet/db/node.socket@6" ErrorPolicyUnhandledApplicationException (MuxError MuxBearerClosed "<socket: 33> closed when reading data, waiting on next header True")
```

Great to know if you have any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a problem but your --database path and your CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH are pointing at different directories.